# Is htaccess-like password protect from PHP possible?

Tags: php, password-protection

You know how htaccess password protection of a folder displays the system's default modal window with a password prompt; I would like to know if I can have that functionality, but only after I programatically calculate whether that protection is needed or not.

Meaning that the same URL may or may not need the password protection in two different situations, so if some of my conditions are not met, I would like it if I could just easily "throw" the login box from PHP, without needing to code (or implement) my own session controller in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes -- see example 1 from http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php which I have reproduced below:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```